# c# enum weird behaviour

Tags: c#, enums

Consider the following example, I trying to override the enum values to be able to parse enums not only with capital letters:

```
    public enum Language
{

    Heb,
    Eng,
    heb = Heb,
    eng = Eng
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var e = "heb";
        Language result;

        Enum.TryParse(e, out result);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

This example returns: "Heb" "Heb"

On the other hand this example:

```
    public enum Language
{

    Heb,
    Eng,
    heb = Heb,
    eng = Eng,
    None
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var e = "heb";
        Language result;

        Enum.TryParse(e, out result);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Returns "heb" "heb"

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6):

When two enumeration values have the same representation, there is no guarantee which is used by `Enum.ToString`. You can shorten the test to just `Console.WriteLine(Language.Heb);`. Since both `Heb` and `heb` are valid outputs, there are no guarantees which one you get. Quoting from [Enum.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx):

> **Notes to Callers**
>
> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return. For example, the following enumeration defines two members, Shade.Gray and Shade.Grey, that have the same underlying value.
>
> ```
> enum Shade
> {
>     White = 0, Gray = 1, Grey = 1, Black = 2 
> }
> ```
>
> The following method call attempts to retrieve the name of a member of the Shade enumeration whose underlying value is 1. The method can return either "Gray" or "Grey", and your code should not make any assumptions about which string will be returned.
>
> ```
> string shadeName = ((Shade) 1).ToString("F");
> ```